# The web browser could not be started. info: hInst="5"

Tags: miktex

I use win 7. when i try to install miktex i get following error. Consequently miktex can not start update. What is the solution

The web browser could not be started.   info: hInst="5"

Comment: Warning: Support for Windows 7 ended on 14th January 2020, more than 2 years ago. You should not use it any longer at least not on a online computer, because of security issues not only for you but also for all data about everyone that are stored on this computer. Please update at least to Window 10. The update is available for free. → [End of support for Windows 7](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/end-of-support) You also should not expect, that any TeX distribution supports a Windows version that has been reached end of live several years ago.

Comment: See also the [MiKTeX prerequists](https://miktex.org/kb/prerequisites). It lists Windows 10 and 11 only, so Windows 7 is not supported any longer.

Comment: i can install it without no problem to my another pc with win7